# How can I size the elements in my table layout relative to screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I have a TableLayout within a LinearLayout, it is a 4x4 grid. I want each cell to be a square and I want the size to scale based on screen size (or rather the size allotted to the TableLayout). I always want all 12 squares shown on the screen. Essentially I want the `layout_height` and `layout_wight` values of each ImageView to be 1/4 of the parent's value. Right now I've just set them to `100dp`. do I need to do something with the `layout_weight` values?

Edit: Ok, so using `layout_weight="1"` for all my `ImageView` objects I was able to get the widths all to be 1/4 of the available space, but now they have 0 height. How can I get the height to also be a function of the `layout_weight`?

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.package.name.MainActivity">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- 1st row -->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        </TableRow>

        <!-- 2nd row -->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

        </TableRow>


        <!-- 3rd row -->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        </TableRow>

        <!-- 4th row -->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this, with the right most column not showing fully. I realize this is because I have them all set to 100dp, but just to give an idea of where I'm currently at:
[image]

Comment: You are using image views. Do you have images to place into the image views or are you using them just to get the color into the squares?

Comment: I will have images eventually, the colors are just a placeholder for now. I kinda scrapped this idea and went with a `GridLayout` instead.

Comment: I was going to say that if your images have a 1x1 ratio, you can specify adjustViewBounds="true" on the ImageViews and the cells will be square.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `1android:stretchColumns="*"`

   ```
   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
   </TableLayout>
   ```
2. You can use `LinearLayout`.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

   </LinearLayout>

   <!-- 2nd row -->
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"

           android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

   </LinearLayout>


   <!-- 3rd row -->
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@+id/tableLayout3"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

   </LinearLayout>

   <!-- 4th row -->
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"

           android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorPrimary"/>

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```